# Why is && strict in compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, lazy-evaluation, compile-time

I am experimenting with basic template metaprogramming. I tried implementing structure templates which help us establish whether their template argument is prime or not. I.e.:

```
template<int N, int D>
struct IsPrime_Descend {
    const static bool val = (N % D != 0) && IsPrime_Descend<N, D - 1>::val;
};

template<int N>
struct IsPrime_Descend<N, 1> {
    const static bool val = true;
};

template <int N>
struct IsPrime {
    const static bool val = IsPrime_Descend<N, N - 1>::val; 
};
```

But the implementation above takes linear time. I wanted to boost it up to `O(sqrt(n))`. Of course, there is the long way of introducing a structure template for calculating the square root and descending from it:

```
template<int N, int D>
struct Sqrt_Descend {
    const static int val = D * D > N ? Sqrt_Descend<N, D - 1>::val : D;
};

template<int N>
struct Sqrt_Descend<N, 1> {
    const static int val = 1;
};

template<int N>
struct Sqrt {
    const static int val = Sqrt_Descend<N, N>::val;
};

template<int N, int D>
struct IsPrime_Descend {
    const static bool val = (N % D != 0) && IsPrime_Descend<N, D - 1>::val;
};

template<int N>
struct IsPrime_Descend<N, 1> {
    const static bool val = true;
};

template <int N>
struct IsPrime {
    const static bool val = IsPrime_Descend<N, Sqrt<N>::val>::val;
};
```

But there's something else I tried:

```
template <int N, int D>
struct IsPrime_Ascend {
    const static bool val = (N % D != 0) && (D * D <= N) && IsPrime_Ascend<N, D + 1>::val;
};

template <int N>
struct IsPrime {
    const static bool val = IsPrime_Ascend<N, 1>::val; 
};
```

I reckoned this snippet to instantiate `IsPrime_Ascend<N, D>` as long as the two preceding conditions (`(N % D != 0) && (D * D <= N)`) are true due to the **laziness of `&&`**. But, apparently, it does not stop when one of them breaks and exceeds template instantiation maximum depth.

So, why is `&&` strict (as in *not lazy*) in compile-time?

Comment: You assumption is wrong. It should not stop, it continuous infinite `IsPrime_Ascend::val = false` after the condition is met. You should add a template specialization that stops template instantiations.

Comment: @273K But why shouldn't it stop? I clearly do not use any `IsPrime_Ascend<N, D>` structures for which `D * D > N`

Comment: You clearly use in the recursion.

Comment: It *is* lazy (better, short-circuit). But when you have an expression `a && b`, before you even start evaluation, you need to know what `a` and `b` are. A compiler won't evaluate `IsPrime::val` in `a && IsPrime::val` if `a == false`, but it will instantiate the template `IsPrime`. It has to: what if you had a specialization of `IsPrime` in which `val` is not a `bool` value but a type alias, `struct IsPrime<...> { using val = void;};`?

Comment: @273K in my understanding of laziness, whenever we encounter `false && condition`, `condition` is not evaluated. Why does this rule does not apply here?

Comment: @Evg doesn't the standard require the compilers to treat dependent names as variables unless the contrary is specified with the `typename` keyword? But I see your point, I guess it is a bit better to say that we need its type, correct?

Comment: You confuse evaluation with instantiation. Before `false && condition` is evaluation, `condition` should be compiled.

Comment: Why are you not writing this as a normal function and slapping `constexpr` on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short-circuit evaluation deals with *evaluation* of expressions. The expression is *still there* in the text of the C++ file, and it therefore must be compiled. If that expression contains a template instantiation, then that template *must be* instantiated. That's how compilation works (unless you use `if constexpr`, which you can't within that context).

If you want to prevent further instantiation, you have to do so via the rules of templates, not the rules of expression evaluation. So you need to use a partial specialization of the template, one which probably uses SFINAE techniques that is active when the condition is true. C++20 makes this easier with a `requires` clause.

Better still, turn `IsPrime_Descend` into a `constexpr` function.